# Angular 9 frontend/springboot backend - How to solve CORS error when calling router.navigate(url)

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors, angular-router

I have Angular frontend and Springboot backend.

My Springboot controller is annotated with `@CorsOrigin` like below which based on my reading will enable CORS on all endpoints in this controller; however that is not the case for some reason:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200") // to prevent CORS error in Angular, use url of Angular app
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/")
public class EmployeeController {

    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository employeeRepository;
    
    @GetMapping("/employees")
    public List<Employee> getAllEmployees() {
        return employeeRepository.findAll();
    }
    
    @PostMapping("/employees/add")
    public Employee createEmployee(@RequestBody Employee employee) {
        return employeeRepository.save(employee);
    }
}
```

My Angular 9 frontend will use a form to create new Employee.  On form submit, I call `onSubmit` which calls `saveEmployee` which calls `goToEmployeeList`:

```
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.employee);
    this.saveEmployee();
  }

 saveEmployee() {
    this.employeeService.createEmployee(this.employee).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      this.goToEmployeeList();
    },
    error => console.log(error));
  }

  /* Once we add new employee, we want to navigate to employee list, so we add new method
     here to use router for that. */
  goToEmployeeList() {
    this.router.navigate(['employees']);
  }
```

However, when I enter employee information in form and click on Submit button I get the CORS error:
[image]

How do I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to close this question but could not since @Geeth tried helping and answering (Much appreciated @Geeth).

The issue was oversight on my side.  I have service in my Angular app with base URL as

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employee"
```

The correct URL is

```
"http://localhost:8080/api/v1/employees"
```

This fixed the above issue.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should remove "/" in at last `@RequestMapping`. It should be `@RequestMapping("/api/v1")`. try this. because of your API end points start with "/".

Comment: thank you.  I actually resolved the issue, the problem was tham my service was trying to access an invalid URL.